# Meaning of "Noble of us" idiom in context

Tags: idioms, meaning-in-context, idiom-meaning

> It would be noble of us to not revel in it, though.

The sentence above has some idioms that I don't know.
What is it going to say? Or when such a sentence could be said?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Noble of us in this case isn't idiomatic. When I Google it, the second definition is:

- having or showing fine personal qualities or high moral principles and ideals.
  *"the promotion of human rights was a noble aspiration"*

So, the sentence is saying that we will show fine personal qualities by not 'revel[ing] in it'.

Comment: Thank you and "reveling in it"?  I guess it means we will show fine personal qualities by not taking pleasure of it (or being joyful of that event)

Comment: Yes! But, what it really means is that it isn't proper to rejoice in front of a defeated opponent. People should win with grace and not gloat.